# How can i parse the following XML script?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I want to parse the following XML File.
I already parsed some basic XML Files, but the problem here is that it has multiple Attributes(I mean the multiple

```
<IF caseSensitive="false" field="Placeholder" inputData="PlaceholderiD"...>)
```

I tried to use the .findall function but the Documentation says quotes aren't allowed, therefore i really have no clue how to solve my Problem.

I already tried to google it but couldn't find a answer to it.
i the following snippet but with the quotes it won't work.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('SomeFile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

root.findall("//*[@caseSensitive='"false"']
for child in root:
print (child.tag, child.attrib)
```

The XML FILE:

```
    <Expressions description="Placeholder" name="Placeholder2">
        <Expression AttributeOne="true" name="JustARandomName">
            <AND AttributeOne="true">
                <OR AttributeOne="true">
                    <IF caseSensitive="false" AttributeTwo="true" field="Placeholder3" AttributeOne="true" inputData="JustAInput1" Operator="true" AnotherOperatorWhichIsNotImportant="false">
                        <SArg dateTime="0">*Something*</SArg>
                    </IF>
                </OR>
                <OR AttributeOne="true">
                    <IF caseSensitive="false" AttributeTwo="false" field="Placeholder4" AttributeOne="true" inputData="JustAInput12" Operator="true" AnotherOperatorWhichIsNotImportant="false">
                        <SArg dateTime="0">Test</SArg>
                    </IF>
                    <AND AttributeOne="true">
                        <IF caseSensitive="false" AttributeTwo="false" field="Placeholder25" AttributeOne="true" inputData="JustAInput13" Operator="true" AnotherOperatorWhichIsNotImportant="false">
                            <SArg dateTime="0">10*</SArg>
                        </IF>
                        <IF caseSensitive="false" AttributeTwo="false" field="Placeholder37" AttributeOne="true" inputData="JustAInput1" Operator="EQUAL" AnotherOperatorWhichIsNotImportant="false">
                            <SArg dateTime="0">true</SArg>
                        </IF>
                        <IF caseSensitive="false" AttributeTwo="true" field="fehlerort" AttributeOne="true" inputData="JustAInput1" Operator="true" AnotherOperatorWhichIsNotImportant="false">
                            <SArg dateTime="0">*Test*</SArg>
                        </IF>
                    </AND> 
...  
... 
...
```

I try to print the specific lines with  `<IF case Sensitive="false" ... Operator="true"... >`
and      `<IF case Sensitive="false" ... Operator="EQUAL"... >`
but NOT  `<IF case Sensitive="false" ... Operator="NOTEQUAL"... >`
If possible just the Field      inputData="..."
But i think once i am able to output the whole line i can solve this myself.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you plan on doing with them but if you wanted to parse them all out into their own lists you could do this

for example

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('Bx_N63x_Befundverifikation_Komplett.xml').getroot()

listCaseSensitive = []
listAtt22 = []
listField = []
```

not going to write them all out but you got the idea then you could do

```
for child in e.iter('IF'):
    listCaseSensitive.append(child.attrib['caseSensitive'])
    listAtt2.append(child.attrib['AttributeTwo'])
    listField.append(child.attrib['field'])

print listCaseSensitive
print listAtt2
print listField
```

this will print out

```
['false', 'false', 'false', ....] //for Case Sensitive
['false','false','false', ...] //for AttributeTwo
['Placeholder3','Placeholder4','Placeholder25', .....] //for field
```

so on and so on I think you have the idea so if you just wanted the InputData it would work the same way and you could grab out just the InputData out of every IF tag

If you are looking for something different just let me know and ill edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use the .findall function but the Documentation says quotes
>   aren't allowed

I think you're referring to this in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) syntax example for `[@attrib='value']`:

> The value cannot contain quotes.

It's just saying the value can't contain quotes. The quotes are still necessary in the XPath to indicate a string.

Try...

```
for child in root.findall(".//*[@caseSensitive='false']"):
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

For the second part of your question (ignoring `Operator="NOTEQUAL"`), I don't think you can do that with XPath in ElementTree. It's XPath support is very limited.

You could do it with [XPath in lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) though...

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("Bx_N63x_Befundverifikation_Komplett.xml")

for input_data in tree.xpath(".//*[@caseSensitive='false'][not(@Operator='NOTEQUAL')]/@inputData"):
    print(input_data)
```